# Put a tab in eclipse next to other tabs

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse how can i minimize a tab to put it next to others tabs without reset perspective

See the following picture

[image: Eclipse]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Via drag and drop: drag where the red arrow starts in you screenshot and drop it on the *g* of *Debug*

Comment: Are you able to change the order of the tabs in a stack via drag and drop? Can you do this: https://youtu.be/Y0-cO9wZj6w?t=1m18s ?

Comment: Does drag and drop work at all (e. g. [Eclipse bug 500694](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500694))?

Comment: i can dot what motioned on video, but when the tab pip-up like a window (like my case "srach had been a window") you can never put it in its place

Comment: Did you grab the _Search_ view on the tab handle (e. g. where your red arrow starts) and not on the window title? Can you drag and drop files between two windows (_Window > New Window_ and drag a file from one _Package Explorer_ to the _Package Explorer_ of the other window)? You're using Linux, right? GTK 2 or 3?